# CSS: position right img behind buttons on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I've a header that is divided in 2 columns using bootstrap: `col-md-6`.

In the right column I've an image that I need to position behind the buttons on the left column on smaller screens.

I think I can achieve this using `media queries` and the `z-index propierty`.  So I took 2 approaches:

a) giving image's container div a z-index of -1, this puts the image behind everythin, even the row's background.

b) givin the buttons a `positive z-index`, so they stay on top of image, but `image` keeps getting on top of `buttons`.

**How can I achieve this?**

[image]

```css
.my_header_bg_color {

    /*background-color: #4FB99F;*/
    /*background-color: #00ADB5;*/
    /*background-color: #6BB983;*/
    background-color: #00AD80;

}


@media (min-width: 200px) {
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 15px; }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {

         bottom: 0;
         position: absolute;
         right: -0px;
         bottom: 0;
         z-index: -1;
     }

}


@media (min-width: 320px) {
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 10px; }

    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

     .my_home_banner_image {

         bottom: 0;
         position: absolute;
         right: -0px;
         bottom: 0;
         z-index: -1;
     }

}


@media (min-width: 481px) {
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


     .my_home_banner_image {

         bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
         z-index: 0;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        z-index: 100;
    }

}


@media (min-width: 641px) {
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 10px; }


}


@media (min-width: 961px) {
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 50px; }

}


@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 10px; }


}


@media (min-width: 1281px) {
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn, h2, p { margin-bottom: 10px; }


}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid my_home_banner my_header_bg_color">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 my_home_banner-left">
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="my_home_banner_left">
                    <p class="my_home_banner_title">Stickers Personalizados</p>
                    <p class="my_home_banner_subtitle">Easy online ordering, 4 day turnaround and free online proofs. Free
                        shipping.</p>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <a href="stickers" class="my_home_buttons btn btn-azul text-white btn-block">Comprar</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <a href="{% url 'shop:SamplePackPage' %}"
                               class="my_home_buttons btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Muestras</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="my_home_banner_image" src="{% static 'img/banner-home.png' %}"
                     width="380px" height="240px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@media (min-width: 320px)` section

```
.my_home_banner_image {

     bottom: 0;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 140px;
     height: auto;
 }
```

and set z-index for button container.

```
 .my_home_banner_left .row{ position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best approach but it will help you to accomplish what you want.
You can have two images:-

## 1. Behind the buttons on the left column

## 2. On the right column

Make image #1 invisible and image#2 visible on large screen and vice versa on smaller screen